# Calculating RF attenuation through plastic container

Tags: rf, xbee, transceiver

I need to provide a customer with an analysis for the maximum range of transmission for a wifi system. I have a raspberry pi with an XBee transceiver module on one end and a laptop with an XBee transceiver on the other end. The XBee states maximum distance of 300 ft. However, the raspberry pi with the transceiver will be house inside a Pelican case (plastic). I need to calculate the maximum distance that our system can operate (at least estimated). Therefore, I would like to know how to calculate how much (percentage-wise), my transmitted signal will be attenuated while passing through the Pelican case.

For example, if I will attenuate the signal by 20% due to being inside the case, my max distance of operation is now 240 ft. (300- 0.2*300).

Can someone assist me in calculating this? If I knew the amount of attenuation per inch of abs plastic for example, then I could make the calculation, but I couldn't find those values.

Thanks,
-D

Comment: Compared to the variability of the range you might measure, due to reflections from walls, buildings, interference from nearby transmitters, the weather, orientation of transmitter and receiver, I would expect that the effect of your plastic box would pale into insignificance.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many more factors that will have an impact on transmission distance than any supposed attenuation through the plastic enclosure that you should adopt a different approach. One practical approach is to use a few of your units and range them apart in various orientations and environments and check if communications is even possible. Then change the distances and/or orientations and try again.

With some careful iterative testing like this you can come up with some real numbers to tell your customers.

Even better is if you can be running some type of test protocol over the RF link during the testing that includes an error correction algorithm. You can use the instances of amount of error correction happening to know when the units are at marginal distances for reliable communications. If the packets were transmitting continuously with results on a display you could simply walk around with the unit.

Answer (score 0):

Most plastics are pure dielectrics, unless they are made conductive by filling them with metal or carbon powder. The attenuation should be minimal.

The only way to be sure is to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: What about reflection due to discontinuity in the dielectric constant at the air/plastic boundary? I know that radars are often housed in radomes, so I assume the reflection is not a major problem. But if you have any information/experience I would be interested.

Comment: radomes are designed with a specific size or set of materials such that the air-dielectric reflection is canceled out.  Keep in mind that if the plastic is electrically small, your in good shape  (less than ~lambda_medium / 10)

Comment: Yes, that is a thing, but the key parameter for reflections is the effective *impedance* of the dielectric, which is a combination of its permittivity and its permeability. In practice, the effect is negligible. As @MichaelKaras says, the best thing is to determine the range empirically.

Comment: I found polystyrene (eps_r = 2.6) to have a transmission factor of -0.35 db for a 7mm thick material. This should be about 93% transmission. This is about as thick as my abs plastic case will be, and I'm assuming the materials differences as far as RF attenuation wont be too drastically different. I was going to estimate about 280 ft. (300*0.93). Again, this is not meant to be exact. Does this seem logical?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into radome design, you'll see that impregnated carbon is one of the worst ingredients to have in the plastic.
You will find that the antennas tuning is likely shifted in frequency by the plastic.    This, in addition to the attenuation caused by the plastic will affect your range.
I agree that the best course of action will be to test it out, at several orientations of the case.